# Create date by two cells - one with date and other with hour in Excel

Tags: excel, date, hour

I would like to create a date like this : 21/10/2013 18:45 in Excel.

```
I have one cell with the date : 21/10/2013
one more cell with : 18:45

How can i create a date like this  21/10/2013 18:45?
```

Answer (score 2):

If your date is in A1 and your time is in A2, then use this formula

```
 =A1+A2
```

Then format the cell as d/m/yyyy hh:mm

Dates in Excel are integers that represent the number of days since 12/31/1899. Times in Excel are decimals between 0 and 1 and represents the fraction of a day that has passed. So noon would be 0.5 because it's 1/2 a day. That's why you can just add them together.

Answer (score 0):

In A1 enter:

=DATE(2013,10,21) and format this cell as "dd/mm/yyyy"

In B1 enter:

=TIME(18,45,0) and format this cell as  "[hh]:mm"